# Message Queues for Windows

Tags: msmq, message-queue, rabbitmq, zeromq

What are the possible message queue services that are available for the .NET stack on Windows?

My use-case is to have worker services running on one or more machines that process jobs put into a queue by the web server to handle background processing.

I know MSMQ comes with Windows.
What about RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ?

Are these stable and do they work reasonably well on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for RabbitMQ, but ZeroMQ has stable windows support in the native source, and the same guy who wrote the python bindings (which I use) wrote the .NET bindings: http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:clr

So, I would say ZeroMQ is trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ has Windows support, just check out the [Rabbit download page.](http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html)
That said, so long as a .net client is available then you can host the queue on any supported platform and still consume in .net